# How to write a custom query for storage?

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, substrate-front-end, query

When you declare a storage say

```
pub type Something<T> = StorageValue<_, u32>;
```

We get query function "something".

But I want to write some specific functions that reads storage and supplies it to frontend.

Say:

```
fn get_something() -> u32 {
       match <Something<T>>::get() {
                None => Err(Error::<T>::NoneValue)?,
                Some(value) => {
                    value + 1
                },
            }
    }
```

Solidity has view functions. How to write view functions or custom queries in substrate?

Answer (score 1):

> We get query function "something".

You don't get this out of the box. You will get this only when you declare `#[pallet::getter(fn something)]` on top of the storage item. This is totally optional, and adds a `fn something` to `impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {}`. You can simply skip the `#[pallet::getter(fn something)]`, and add your custom getter/view function:

```
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
  fn get_something() -> u32 {
    // custom logic
  } 
}
```

Comment: Ya, I have done it, not sure why its not showing on pallet inspector substrate-node-template

Comment: No. I am unable to make it work.