# Custom query for storage

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot-js

I want to write custom query based on this [answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/1694/213):

```
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
    pub fn hello_world() -> u128 {
        10
    }
}
```

But the problem is, it is not exposed in query of pallet inspector in substrate-node-template.

Neither I could query with polkadot js api.

```
  const queryResHandler = result =>
    result.isNone ? setStatus('None') : setStatus(result.toString()) 
const opts = []
let data = api.query.templateModule.hello_world(...opts, queryResHandler)
or 
let data = api.query.templateModule.helloWorld(...opts, queryResHandler)
```

Gives error

```
TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on undefined, which is a undefined and not a function
```

What more I need to do?

Comment: You may want to create your custom RPCs. https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/custom-rpcs/

Comment: Documentation is scarce for implementation. Any code examples.

Comment: You can check out this [pallet](https://github.com/JoshOrndorff/recipes/tree/master/pallets/sum-storage) from [substrate recipes](https://substrate.recipes/runtime-api.html). And [here](https://substrate.recipes/custom-rpc.html#rpc-to-call-a-runtime-api) how to call a runtime api using RPC. You can also take a look at [Subsocial's profile pallet](https://github.com/dappforce/subsocial-node/tree/master/pallets/profiles)

Comment: https://substrate.recipes/runtime-api.html Trying to implement runtime api, but there is version conflict error for sp-api.  error: failed to select a version for `parity-util-mem`.
    ... required by package `sc-service v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=monthly-2021-10#bf9683ee)`

Comment: Make sure that you're using the same substrate tag for the whole project. If different, it may cause conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

As some in the comments mentioned you can create a custom RPC that queries a value from storage.

Check [this answer on StackExchange](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/5555/2762) about how to do it or [this tutorial](https://hackmd.io/JpJCbu0nTa2jym0za1Tggw), that creates a custom RPC query from the pallet template in the Substrate node template.